How long can a Thin-Blood stay awake before having to sleep?
It is implied in the books that Thin-Bloods can operate during the day, even more heavily so if the have the Daydrinker merit. But I can not find any elaboration on how long a Thin-Blood can stave off day-sleep.

No longer than any other vampire; their main advantage is resisting sunlight
The short version is that the Thin-Blooded are no better at staying awake during the day than other vampires. But they are better able to act during daylight hours, since sunlight is much less dangerous for them.
The rules for waking in the day are on page 218, in the Awakening section under Prices of the Blood:

Awakening during the day requires a Humanity roll at a Difficulty depending on the level of crisis. A fire or other life-threatening situation is Difficulty 3; an urgent message or decision is Difficulty 4; an inconvenience to deal with is Difficulty 5 or higher.
Once awakened from day-sleep, a vampire can only act for a single scene. At the end of that period, to remain awake longer, they must make a Humanity roll at Difficulty 3; a win permits an additional scene. A critical win lets them stay awake for as long as needed. If a Kindred acts during daylight hours, the maximum dice pool they can roll equals their Humanity rating.

Note there are no hard and fast rules for how long they can stay awake - it’s expressed only in scenes. So the length of time is limited only by the vampire’s ability to resist this part of the Curse, represented by the rolls.
There are a few exceptions to these rules. The main one - and the one most likely to impact Thin-Blooded - is having very high Humanity (page 236). Vampires with Humanity 9 can choose to wake an hour before sunset, and those with Humanity 10 can wake at any time as a human would, in both cases without a roll. The rules note that they still need sleep - they’re just not required to be nocturnal.
The other exceptions are also rare, and likely out of reach for Thin-Bloods: the Blood Sorcery ritual “Wake with Evening’s Freshness” (page 276), and the lore powers “First-Cursed” (Bahari, page 382) and “Greet the Sun” (Golconda, page 389). All of these options have limitations.
By contrast, the rules for Thin-Blooded have no exceptions for the rules for waking during the day. On page 111 they say:

Despite this, your thin-blood character is still fundamentally a vampire, and unless otherwise stated follows the same rules as other vampires in this book.

So Thin-Bloods still have to make Humanity checks to wake and stay awake during the day, unless they have very high Humanity.
This makes their main advantage as day-time operatives their resistance to sunlight. They take only Superficial damage, and can guard against the sun with fewer clothes than other vampires (pages 113 and 221).
As you mention in the question, the Thin-Blooded Merit “Day Drinker” (page 183) takes this further: daylight robs a Day Drinker of their vampiric abilities and makes them weaker, but they take no damage from the sun. The Merit doesn’t make it easier to wake or stay awake during the day, though, and specifically says:

You still suffer from Hunger, however, and sooner or later you’ll need to sleep.

Even the “Day Watch” coterie type on page 198, which requires the characters to be Thin-Blooded with the Day Drinker Merit or have “another means of remaining active by day”, doesn’t provide an easier way to wake. A Storyteller could rule that being chosen for Day Watch counts as an urgent duty or even life-threatening situation, though, perhaps lowering the difficulty of the required Humanity rolls.
